# BadRequest error on deployment of yaml file

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-deployment, kubernetes-cluster

getting a bad request error on deployment of yaml file in kubernetes cluster.

```
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "deployment.yaml": service in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Service: no kind "service" is registered for version "v1" in scheme "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api/legacyscheme/scheme.go:29"
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "deployment.yaml": deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: no kind "deployment" is registered for version "apps/v1" in scheme "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api/legacyscheme/scheme.go:29"
```

kubernetes cluster is version 1.14.7 with 2 nodepools. one is the default nodepool with a linux node and the other is a windows node pool (node count 1) for windows containers. I am logging into the Azure CLI within the portal itself and running the kubectl commands.

tried apiVersion: apps/v1beta1 but no good.

```
kubectl version

Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.0", GitCommit:"2bd9643cee5b3b3a5ecbd3af49d09018f0773c77", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-09-18T14:36:53Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.6", GitCommit:"96fac5cd13a5dc064f7d9f4f23030a6aeface6cc", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-08-19T11:05:16Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Here is the deployment.yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:  
  name: sampleapp
  labels:
    app: sampleapp
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer  
  ports:
  - name: proxy
    protocol: TCP
    port: 9163
    targetPort: 9163
  - name: banyan
    protocol: TCP
    port: 23010
    targetPort: 23010      
  selector:
    app: sampleapp
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sampleapp
  labels:
    app: sampleapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sampleapp
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "beta.kubernetes.io/os": windows
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: docker-secret
      containers:
      - name: proxyservice
        image: docker.azurecr.io/proxyservice:326
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9163        
        env:
        - name: sup_hostname
          value: "xac-dev-docker4.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com"
      - name: syncservice
        image: docker.azurecr.io/syncservice:326
        ports:
        - containerPort: 23010
        env:
        - name: broker_hostname
          value: "" 
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sampleapp
```

Expected result should be that the yaml file be deployed.

not sure if this is related to indentation of the file. Is the yaml file wrong or am i missing something?

Comment: It's not related to indentation of the file. I checked, deployed perfectly for me.

Comment: Yeah, it worked for me too. @RAnand, I think the issue here is related to your kubernetes cluster.

Comment: you can do `kubectl explain service` and `kubectl explain deployment` to see what are the versions registered for your cluster. Then change the `apiVersion` to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the error description the issue is with the version compatibility of the deployment YAML.

`no kind "service" is registered for version "v1"`

This means the resources type **service** is not recognized by Kubernetes API with version **v1** as mentioned in the deployment yaml's **apiVersion: v1**

Try

This issue has the solution which is to use the appropriate apiVersion in the deployment YAML. [enter link description here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/55894)

Here are some references.

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/#api-groups
- [for version 1.14] https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.14/

---

**Client - Server Version Mismatch**

Also worth mentioning is the version mismatch between the client and server kubernetes version. Kubernetes supports compatibility of master being behind the client by 1 minor version but that is not really recommended. Since your versions are 2 minor versions apart I would recommend making the server to atelast match the client's version.

Reference - https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/release/versioning.md#supported-releases-and-component-skew

Comment: thanks for the help. the links were useful. I was able to figure out the issue. In my yaml file i had placed Service and Deployment in lowercase. Silly me :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)